# A problem occurred configuring project ':background_locator'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

While build the app get an error like

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':background_locator'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\background_locator-1.6.12\android\build.gradle' from cache.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How to solve this issue

Comment: Have you already tried a `flutter clean` followed by a `pub get`?

Be aware that right now, the current version of the plugin doesn't work properly with null safety enabled (this is a bug). Some PRs exist in the Github repository that resolve this, so you could override the package with that version or roll back to an earlier version instead. Even then, it should normally compile as expected.